# Apple Mach-O Librarian Error, flags are invalid: -ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob

I was trying to include google's Admob SDK to my cocos2d project, however, I got following error:

```
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
> -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
> can't locate file for: -lwebp
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
> file: -lwebp is not an object file (not allowed in a library) Command
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool
> failed with exit code 1
```

the error message is:

Command `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1`

has been stuck here for a while and anyone know what's the potential problem it is?

I followed AdMob's instruction and added -ObjC to the end of the linker flags.

Comment: Looks like two unrelated errors: _-dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC_ and _can't locate file for: -lwebp_. The second is likely solved by including the right library path for the webp library.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of where you added -ObjC

Comment: in other Linker Flags......  both Debug and Release

Comment: Did you ever end up resolving this issue? I am currently seeing something similar.